# Package javax.json not available on Java EE 7 Project

Tags: java, java-ee-7, tomcat8

I am working on a Java EE project in which I use Tomcat 8 as the server container. I read that Tomcat 8 uses Java EE 7 container which has Java JSON Processing API for JSON Processing. Attempts to take advantage this Java EE 7 feature keep failing as I cannot not import Files from javax.json packages. Netbeans reports that package javax.json.* package does not exist show in the picture below. I will appreciate your help, please!

[image]

Comment: Are you using some build tools?

Comment: Not really, I created the project through netbeans interface, But I guess netbeans might be using Apache Ant

Comment: The problem is that Tomcat8 could have the Api for JSon processing and then you don't get exception at Runtime, but from your question i see that you have problem at level compilation and then you have to update your build path to solve the problem

Comment: You are right, I can't comply probably because JSON API is not in the path. My assumption is that this is bundled with Java EE 7. However, I am already looking for a third party lib to take care of that. It is unfortunate though. I will really appreciate any solution that will not involve external lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to download and add to my lib; [javax.json-1.0.4.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar) which gives me the Json Processing capability that I needed.

Comment: My suggestion is that of use a build tool like maven or gradle to manage depencencies i the project

Comment: @Skizzo I really appreciate your support so far, I will like to know if there is/are advantages of using maven build tool over my approach?

Comment: Move the conversation at this [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61403/room-for-skizzo-and-paullo)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's true that Tomcat 8 'uses Java EE 7' in the way you think it does.  Tomcat is wonderful, but it has never been a full-on Java EE.  It *is* a servlet container, but that's not quite the same as something like JBoss.  As previous poster said, download it and add it to your lib folder.  I always make sure to have a local Tomcat on my dev machine, and add it's Tomcat lib as one of my global libraries.  When something is not showing up, then I know I need to maven it and then add it lib in the jar/war.

FYI there is the TomEE project, http://tomee.apache.org/tomcat-java-ee.html which is a full-on Java EE version of Tomcat, but personally I like plain old Tomcat and just adding what's needed.